# ERROR: "Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from" then do something

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I have a SoapClient that is falling sometimes.

```
// send request
$client = new SoapClient("http://XXXXXXXXX.org/NowPlaying.asmx?WSDL");
$result = $client->GetNowPlaying();

// get array of items
$arr = $result->GetNowPlayingResult->PlayerItem;
```

In those times I would like to show something insted of the Error Message. I have done many if/else statements but anything work.

Can you help me?

Comment: How are you displaying the information? What would you like to display besides the error? Also have you tried using `try`/`catch` to capture the error and take the appropriate action?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a `try`/`catch`?

```
try {
    // send request
    $client = new SoapClient("http://XXXXXXXXX.org/NowPlaying.asmx?WSDL");
    $result = $client->GetNowPlaying();

    // get array of items
    $arr = $result->GetNowPlayingResult->PlayerItem;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Sorry, there was a problem!<br><br>';
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```